# Contents of tabPanel is not shown

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch

I'm new to sencha touch framework and I have one problem I cannot solve myself.

When I create TabPanel inside Panel, the TabPanel's content will not show up, only the toolbar where the buttons are. Here is my test code.

```
Ext.setup({
    onReady: function() {
        tabpanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
            id: 'tabpanel',
            items: [{
                title: 'facebook',
                html: 'facebook'
            },{
                title: 'google',
                html: 'google',
            },{
                title: 'twitter',
                html: 'twitter'
            }]
        });
        mainview = new Ext.Panel({
            fullscreen: true,
            id: 'mainview',
            items: [tabpanel]
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a layout to your mainview.

```
mainview = new Ext.Panel({
    layout: 'fit',
    fullscreen: true,
    id: 'mainview',
    items: [tabpanel]
});
```